# Why did the US government bail out US airlines before the airlines issued new bonds and equity?

Tags: airline

I focus DAL and UAL, but don't hesitate to bring up other North American airlines. Around [Apr 15 2020](https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/us-government-warren-buffett-big-4-airlines-shareholder-bailout-2020-4-1029088827) (anyone remember the exact date?), [Delta and United Airlines](https://www.businesstraveller.com/features/these-airlines-have-received-a-bailout/) accessed funding as part of the CARES Act.

> It [Delta] will receive $5.4 billion from the Payroll Support Program (PSP) to support staff salaries and benefits, which comes in two forms: a direct grant of $4.1 billion, and a low-interest rate loan of $1.6 billion.  The Atlanta-based airline will also provide the government with warrants to acquire about 1% of Delta stock at $24.39 per share over five years.
>
> It [United] will receive $5.0 billion total the airline expects to receive, approximately $3.5 billion will be a direct grant and approximately $1.5 billion will be a low interest rate loan. These funds secured from the U.S. Treasury Department will be used to pay for the salaries and benefits of tens of thousands of United Airlines employees. In connection with the Payroll Support Program, the airline’s parent company also expects to issue warrants to purchase approximately 4.6 million shares of UAL common stock to the federal government.

On Apr 21 2020, UAL [announced the pricing of an underwritten public offering of 39,250,000 shares of its common stock, at a public offering price of $26.50 per share.](https://hub.united.com/ual-announces-pricing-public-offering-common-stock-2645797267.html)

On Apr 22, DAL [intended to raise $3 billion in debt by offering senior secured notes and entering into a new credit facility](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-delta-air-offering/delta-to-raise-3-billion-in-debt-to-combat-virus-fallout-idUSKCN22500Q).

## My questions

1. Why didn't the US Treasury require DAL and UAL to issue new bonds and equity BEFORE loaning and granting them money under CARES Act?
2. Why didn't DAL and UAL try to raise capital beforehand?  Was UAL just being selfish and greedy, trying to avoid seeing its share price drop? I know  issuing new equity will [dilute and lower share prices](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/stocks/11/dangers-of-stock-dilution.asp).
3. But even if UAL was just self-serving, why didn't it issue bonds like DAL? Then UAL  won't dilute its share price!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52333/why-are-us-airlines-being-bailed-out-using-loans-instead-of-equity-injections

Comment: Given the current market, and the near to medium term prospects for airlines as a profitable business, who would want to buy the bonds/equity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few key distinctions to keep in mind.

1. The important date to take note of is not when they assessed the funds, but when the funds were made available to them by law i.e. on [March 27, 2010](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/748/text)
2. Other dates to keep in mind are when the bill was introduced. In the US Senate, it was introduced on [March 19, 2020](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/senate-bill/3548/actions?KWICView=false)

The reason these distinctions are important is to assess congressional/treasury decision making through the lens of market conditions at the time.

With regards to debt, by mid-March corporate debt markets [had largely seized up](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/wall-street-fear-flashbacks-to-2008-of-forced-selling-in-9-trillion-us-corporate-bond-market-2020-03-14) and there were very tangible concerns there could be a 2008-like event without market intervention. Delta airline bonds were already trading at a [22% yield](https://www.barrons.com/articles/delta-marriott-investment-grade-companies-bonds-distress-51584628415) which is essentially distressed debt levels, and by March 24th a few days before the bill was signed, its [credit rating was downgraded to junk](https://fortune.com/2020/03/24/delta-credit-downgrade-junk-corporate-bonds-coronavirus-airlines/). Even as of late Feb, the [debt market and airlines in particular](https://wolfstreet.com/2020/03/08/its-crazy-in-the-treasury-market-but-the-corporate-bond-market-is-starting-to-dial-in-the-coronavirus/) had already started showing signs of the trouble to come. Summary: Debt markets were not a viable option.

With regards to equity, between Feb 19 (mkt peak) and Mar 19 (the day the bill was introduced), Delta stock had already fallen more that 60% while United had fallen more than 70%. The broader stock market had just experienced the [fastest 30% sell-off](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/03/23/this-was-the-fastest-30percent-stock-market-decline-ever.html) in history. Summary: Equity markets were not a viable option.

To your last question about issuing bonds vs equity. This is a subjective decision without a clear-cut answer why one should do one vs the other. You would have to have a clear view of each company's capital structure i.e. how much debt do they already have, and how much more debt do they have the appetite to add to their capital structure. What is their ability to service existing debt plus any additional debt raised? What is their outlook/certainty around future cash flows? All these factors would influence going one route vs the other.

Finally, although I understand the rationale behind not raising debt or equity, and congressional intervention to prevent economic collapse, that doesn't mean i support bailing out airlines (even when/if there is an equity component to it). Equity investing is all about risk-taking, and I can't reconcile why some people's risk should be socialized at taxpayer expense. Also, there is something conveniently disingenuous about selectively being ok with certain types of welfare (which is what bailouts are), and not others.

Answer (score 0):

If a re-organization were to happen in bankruptcy, the shareholders are usually wiped out while the bondholders can become the new shareholders of the re-organized company.

So DAL in issuing bonds might be essentially offering an equity position in a future company while UAL in issuing common stock might be trying to save the current company.

My suggestion was for a streamlined and legislated re-organization process whereby current bondholders would be converted to common stock such that the company becomes debt-free as the stockholders are diluted. The bondholders would win but would have no negotiation power. Accountants would calculate the re-organized company. No government funding would be required.

But the current government funding stabilizes the companies which then allows for the raising of new capital.